# How the node in Corda restore data in Enterprise Corda Version

Tags: corda

I set up a network with 2 normal Node (NodeA and NodeB) and 1 Notary. If NodeA has shut down and lose apart of its database (about current states), how can We ensure that the network may run as well. And how does NodeA restore this data that loss? (Can Enterprise Corda Version help me in this case?)

Comment: What do you mean by "lose a part of its database"? Do you mean that a database admin deletes some of the data from the database?

Comment: Yes, for example, Vault of NodeA and NodeB have same states [State1, State2, State3] NodeA then lose data about State1, so NodeA's vault contains [State2, State3] while NodeB's vault still contains [State1, State2, State3].

Answer (score 0):

When a database admin deletes your data, Corda will not be able to help you. You are responsible for your own database. You need to ensure that only authorized parties have permissions to access the database. 
Let's say that PartyA now does not have latest states/ data for your custom tables. In this scenario, PartyA can request PartyB for this missing state if PartyB was also a participant to the state. It depends on PartyB whether to share this state to PartyA.

There is a built in flow to send the state from one party to other

```
SendStateAndRefFlow(otherSideSession: FlowSession, stateAndRefs: List<StateAndRef<*>>)
```